# How to list all elements starting with a specific id using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to list all IDs that start with a specific name (but not starting with another name).
The problem I am getting is my routine is not alerting out the name of each ID.

Can anybody see where I am going wrong?

```js
$(function() { 
  $("body").on('click', '#submit', function(e) {
  $('[id^="supplier_"]:not([id^="supplier_insert_"])').each(function(){
     alert($(this).id);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="select_insert_1">
<input id="select_1">
<input id="select_insert_2">
<input id="select_2">
<input id="other_1">
<input id="other_2">
<button id="submit">
Submit
</button>
```

TIA!

Comment: `id` is a property of the DOM element, not the collection that jQuery returns. I think you mean `alert($(this).prop('id'));` (or simply `alert(this.id);`)

Comment: adding to what @George said, as you're looking for a collection of elements using an `id` note that elements`id`s should be unique and not used on more than 1 element on any given DOM tree

Comment: Thank you - that did the trick!